# How to listen SoftInputMethod's show/hide event?

Tags: android

I try to implement it by using BroadcastReceiver in this way.
But it does not work.The show/hide event never come into my receiver.

```
        filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_INPUT_METHOD_CHANGED);

        filter.setPriority(IntentFilter.SYSTEM_HIGH_PRIORITY);
        registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
```

I hope some nice man can help me.

That's all

Comment: where is your question?

Comment: What does not work ? Follow theses guidelines : http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Sorry,I forget to post the codes, I post it just now.

Answer (score 0):

Hope it's help you.

```
OnGlobalLayoutListener mOnGlobalLayoutListener;
private void performListenKeyboard() {
    if (mOnGlobalLayoutListener == null) {
        mOnGlobalLayoutListener = new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {

                final int screenHeight = mRootView.getRootView().getHeight();
                int keyboardHeight = screenHeight - mRootView.getHeight();
                if (keyboardHeight < screenHeight / 3 || !isShowKeyboard) {
                    return;
                }
                // keyboard show,do something

                // at last , remove listener
                mRootView.getRootView().getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(mOnGlobalLayoutListener);
            }
        };
    }
    // register GlobalLayoutListener callback
    mRootView.getRootView().getViewTreeObserver()
            .addOnGlobalLayoutListener(mOnGlobalLayoutListener);
}
```